# voicecommand: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by voicecommand) on raspberry pi

Tags: curl, libcurl, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, raspbian-buster

I tried setting up voicecommand on my raspberry pi running the latest version of raspbian buster, but everytime I try to run a voicecommand command I get this error:

```
voicecommand: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by voicecommand)
```

I looked at a lot of other posts but none of them solved my problem.

I tried installing libcurl3 but I get this message:

```
Package libcurl3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libcurl4

E: Package 'libcurl3' has no installation candidate
```

I also reinstalled libcurl4 and curl with no change on the error
I have installed `libcurl4` and other dev packages and as far as I can see in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` I have `libcurl-gnutls.so.3` and `libcurl-gnutls.so.4` but not `libcurl3`

Comment: Where did you download this "voicecommand" binary?

Comment: I found the instructions on steven hickson's website. I downloaded from his repository a suite that installs many dependensies including voicecommand.

Comment: It's probably linked to an ancient version of cURL. You could try to compile it yourself: https://github.com/StevenHickson/PiAUISuite/tree/master/VoiceCommand, sadly a lot of the paths and options seem to be hardcoded in the Makefiles, so don't just blindly run make or make install.

Comment: I am currently trying to install it on raspbian stretch that has an installation canditate for libcurl3 that I'm hoping will help